# How can one convert an uncertainty expression (e.g. 3.23 +/- 0.01) from a string to a float?

Tags: python, sympy

I taking some data from a .csv file and placing it into a dict within my Python script, when I noticed a discrepancy in one of columns that contained values of uncertainty (e.g. 3.23 +/- 0.01). After a new table was built and the results were exported to Excel, this column would not sort itself numerically– only the very first value was treated like a number, while the rest of the values were treated like they were an expression.

I suspect this might have to do with the fact that, when I first reading the .csv file, it was read with 'rU' (read universal characters, instead of 'rb' for read binary). I did this since the original +/- symbol in the .csv file was not being read properly. So after the .csv file was read in, it had ' \xb1 ' as a placeholder for the +/- symbol, which I subsequently replaced again with ' +/- '.

```
import csv
import re    

folder_contents={}
with open("greencandidates.csv", "rU") as csvfile:
    green= csv.reader(csvfile, dialect= 'excel')
    for line in green:
        candidate_number= line[0]
        fluorescence= line[1].replace(" \xb1 "," +/- ")
        folder_contents[candidate_number]= [fluorescence]
```

However, given that there is a lot of data that gets processed from the original .csv file, I really would like to be able to sort the data in descending order (largest to smallest). Although there is a module that does allow for the creation of expressions of uncertainty, (https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/), I'm not sure how to use it in order to make the expressions of uncertainty be treated as floats that can be arranged in descending order. I posted a way in which uncertainty expressions can be created with the Sympy package below.

```
from uncertainties import ufloat

x = ufloat(1, 0.1)  # x = 1+/-0.1
```

Comment: sorted how? Would 3.1 +/- 0.1 be a larger (or smaller) value than 3.11 +/- 0.05? Are you looking to simply extract the float component of the uncertainty expression, and sort by that value?

Comment: @DavidZemens I want it to be sorted so that 31.1 +/- 0.01 is a larger value than 3.11 +/- 0.01. For the sake of simplicity, I think it would be better to only consider the value of the first part of the uncertainty expression (i.e. the number before the +/- symbol) in the evaluation of its size.

Comment: OK, so if you have the uncertainy expression as a string, split on the `+/-` and trim the resulting value, convert to float, and sort based on that in to a list or other data structure. Would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a key function in your sort, such as:

```
def u_float_key(num):
    return float(num.split('+')[0])
```

Then you can use the built-in sorted even with strings:

```
sorted(results, key=u_float_key, reverse=True)

>>> test = ["1+/-1", "0.2+/-0", "4+/-2", "3+/-100"]
>>> sorted(test, key=ufloatkey)
['0.2+/-0', '1+/-1', '3+/-100', '4+/-2']
```

Comment: although your method works, for some reason, Excel does not seem to want to sort the values based on the first integer (i.e. the number before the +/- symbol). It keeps sorting the values by only the first digit instead. I have run your code exactly as is (with my values) in my IDE and it returns the numbers sorted correctly, so I really don't know what is happening here.

Comment: I decided ultimately to forego keeping the entire expression of uncertainty, and only keeping the main integer to make the data processing and visualization easier. If we need to go back and get all the values of uncertainty, then we'll probably do `float(num.split('+')[2])` in order to get said numbers, then put them back in using 
`x = ufloat(1, 0.1)`.

Comment: @BobMcBobson a native `sorted(test)` seems to work without a key, **iif** none of them have a difference in number of digits (all single digit +- whatever)